# Mutual Authentication with HttpClient

Tags: https, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am going to present my problem:

My web application submit a form by https to a server that it needs client certificate for set the communication. It works fine, when i submit the form, the https server asks me for a certificate, i select my certificate and the server response me. But now, i want to post to https server from a servlet with HttpClient because i want to manage the response from https server, and here i have problems...

My code to send a post with HttpClient is:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

// in the truststore i have the https server certificates for establish connection
// from my client to https server       
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(TRUESTORE_PATH));       
KeyStore truststore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
truststore.load(instream, KEY_TRUESTORE_PASS.toCharArray());

// in the keystore i have the client certificate but without private key because,
// in theory, i shouldn't know it   
FileInputStream otherinstream = new FileInputStream(new File(KEYSTORE_PATH));
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(otherinstream,KEY_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SocketFactory(keystore,KEY_STORE_PASS,truststore);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://remote_server_with_client_authentication");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
```

When i execute this code, in an unit test for example, i have response from https server, but it tells me that i am **not authorized**. I suspect that i can't authenticate with the https server because the keystore has the client certificate but whitout private key, then i am not authorized.

Then, Is there some way to establish communication with the https server with a client certificate selected by the user?

Thanks!

Comment: For this to work properly you will need to have the private key of the certificate you want to present to the server.